# Why does my parity sync get stuck all the time?

Tags: parity

I have a server set up with a node to read from the blockchain, so I don't have to run my node on my computer all the time. Sometimes the node gets stuck and I reset the blockchain with

```
./parity/target/release/parity -light db kill
```

now It gets stuck all the time and I have to delete the blockchain over and over again because the node gets stuck at block 2.4M-2.6M and stops syncing.

```
web3.eth.syncing
{
    currentBlock: 2681433,
    highestBlock: 4801999,
    startingBlock: 0,
    warpChunksAmount: null,
    warpChunksProcessed: null
}
```

what can I do to resync the blockchain (with warp this should not take longer than a few hours...)

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Upgrade to latest Parity (1.7.11) solved it. They upgrade wrap nodes.

- https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases/tag/v1.7.11
- https://github.com/paritytech/parity/pull/7287